# Malloc and Realloc for Int Array

Tags: c, for-loop, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I've just started learning `malloc()` and `realloc()` and when testing them, I came across this issue with reallocating the size of an int array.

the program is supposed to make an array, initially of size two, but it's supposed to increase its size and add values to it ten times. However it doesn't increase its size and the output ends up being `array = {0,1}` when it should be `array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *array= malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(int)*(2+x));
        array[x] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++) {
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

could someone explain why it doesn't work?? I've tried looking for answers but none of this makes sense to me lol.

Comment: `sizeof(pointer)` is always the same no matter how much memory it points to. That information is not baked in, you'll need to keep track of the memory size manually.

Comment: Because `array` is a _pointer_, `sizeof(array)` is `sizeof(int *)` which is 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine. For most [modern] machines, `sizeof(int)` is 4 [but could be 2 or even 8], so we end up dividing a fixed number by a fixed number based on the architecture. So, we could have: 1, 2, 4, 8 as values. But, never something like 1000.

Comment: Store a count of the number of elements in the array, and adjust that count when you allocate more space.  Don't forget to check that the memory allocations worked.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( int * )/sizeof( int )
```

and yields either 2 or 1 depending on the used system.

Also the expression `(2+x)` in this statement

```
array = realloc(array, sizeof(int)*(2+x));
```

used in each iteration of the for loop does not make sense.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
enum { N = 10 };
size_t n = 2;

int *array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
for ( int x = 0; x < N; x++ ) {
    if ( n <= x )
    {
        n += 2;
        array = realloc( array, n * sizeof( int ) );
    }
    array[x] = x;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n",array[i]);
}

free(array);
```

In general it is safer to use an intermediate pointer in the call pf `realloc` like for example

```
int *tmp = realloc( array, n * sizeof( int ) );
if ( tmp != NULL ) array = tmp;
```

Otherwise you can loose the allocated memory if the call of `realloc` will return a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sizeof(array)` will just return the size of the pointer (8 bytes on a 64-bit system). You need to track the array size in another variable. For example...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *array= malloc(sizeof(int));
    int size;
    for (size = 0; size < 10; size++) {
        array = realloc(array, sizeof(int)*(1+size));
        array[size] = size;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
    printf("array size: %ld\n",size*sizeof(int));
    free(array);
}
```